# How to set orientation to intent.putExtra?

Tags: android, android-intent, orientation, contacts, android-contacts

I have add new contact button and when I press this button, android is opening system new contact page.

***Opening page is android system page, not inside my app page.***

```
MyActivity(){

 addToContactView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 1);
   //intent.putExtra("orientation", "portrait"); //like this
   startActivityForResult(intent);
   });
 }
```

**Manifest:**

```
<activity
  android:name=".MyActivity"
  android:configChanges="locale"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

I set portrait screen orientation at MyActivity. But android system new contact page is opening landscape mode.

Can orientation be set into intent?

Comment: you can change device orientation before open contact app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718317/control-default-auto-rotate-screen-in-my-application  and then return device on old orientation after adding contact

Comment: your welcome, hope it help you. you can using upvote button if comment was helpful

Comment: Thank you very much but it is not working :(

Comment: did you change system system orientation as well? when open contact app check the notification: is rotation set?

Comment: yeap I guess that because of this page is not application page, it is not working.

Comment: also check this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587085/how-can-i-globally-force-screen-orientation-in-android

Comment: your welcome. posted as answer, you can use upvote and mark as answer. have fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must globaly change the orientation before opening contact app. 
see this topic: [How can I globally force screen orientation in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587085/how-can-i-globally-force-screen-orientation-in-android)